# Is there a way to modify 'operator->' so that 'z->im' returns imaginary part of complex number

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a struct Cmplx which models complex numbers.

```
class Cmplx{
  double x;
  double y;
 public:
  Cmplx(int X, int Y){x = X; y = Y;}
  double& operator->(...){...}
}
```

I need to implement the operator, such that

```
int main(){
Cmlpx z(1,2);
z->im = 5;
z->re = 2;
}
```

Changes my complex number into (2,5); I know how to do it when im and re are strings, but have no idea how to do it like this.

Comment: If you're going to provide access to the members like that, why not make the members public?

Comment: 1) Rename 'x' and 'y' to `im` and `re`. 2) Make them public. 3) Profit!

Comment: Please don't.  `->` should only be for pointer types.  Doing things like this is why some languages (looking at you Java) don't allow operator overloading.

Comment: If you don't want to make those members public, consider different overloaded functions other than `->`, like `imaginary()` and `real()`.

Comment: I can make x and y public, and rename them to re and im, but it wouldn't work since z in this case is not a pointer. Also this was an exam excercise so i cant just implement it the way i want to.

Comment: I think idea was that i can only acces them through the operator and not directly. (Even though that makes no sense in practise, but again this was an exam)

Comment: @Nasal "*it wouldn't work since `z` in this case is not a pointer*" - you would simply use `.` instead of `->`, eg: `Cmlpx z(1,2); z.im = 5; z.re = 2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might abuse of `operator->` that way:

```
struct ComplexRef
{
    ComplexRef* operator->() { return this;}
    double& re;
    double& im;
};

class Cmplx{
  double x;
  double y;
public:
  Cmplx(int X, int Y){x = X; y = Y;}
  ComplexRef operator->(){ return {x, y}; }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c52b0bf88c993f4b)

The overload of `operator ->` must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which `operator ->` is in turn overloaded.

Comment: If I may ask, why does the 'ComplexRef* operator->' get called anyway? z-> is by my understanding a ComplexRef object, and then we look at its 'im' component, am i getting it wrong? Also why isn't the Dot in '(z->).im' necessary

Comment: @Nasal: `c->m` call `operator->` until result type is a pointer. You might do `z.operator->().im` to use dot, but `z->im` is equivalent to `z.operator->().operator->()->im`.